# $wpdb and Referential integrity in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I use referential integrity to enforce data relationships in my MYSQL database. I have 3 tables: cars - members - ownerships. The ownerships have a relation to the cars-table and to the members-table. When I try to remove a car from the cars-table, $wpdb only informs me in text (english) that this action conflicts with the referential integrity.
I would prefer to recieve an error-code, so I can identify it is not a real database problem, but in this case it is a specific error with referential integity. But unfortunately I only receive a text-message in $wpdb->last_error.

Is there a solution to make a distinction between referential integrity errors and regular errors?
Before I used the $wpdb solution I used $connect, and in that solution it worked fine and I could filter the error-code.
Hope someone can help me!
Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wpdb->last_error` only stores what is output by `mysqli_error()`, a native PHP function, so the class is not generating its own error; rather, it's just repeating to you the error from MySQL. `$wpdb` unfortunately doesn't output `mysqli_errno()`.

Comment: This was what I was afraid of. Where could I drop a request to add this information?

Comment: I found that the error-code $wpdb->dbh->errno contains the error code I was looking for. Nevertheless I prefer an update of the wpdb class so I can use $wpdb->last_errno. I dropped the request already